# Re-label Year ID data nested in person to time point (enumerate time point)

Tags: r, time-series, recode

I have a longitudinal data where respondents recruited as cohort. Right now, I have year in which they took the survey. But I want to create a new column simply counting if it is the first, second, or third time a person took the survey.

Original Table

| PersonID | SurveyYear | SurveyQ1Rating | SurveyQ2Rating | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2013 | 5 | 4 | f |
| 12 | 2012 | 4 | 4 | f |
| 12 | 2010 | 3 | 3 | f |
| 2 | 2007 | 4 | 4 | m |
| 2 | 2008 | 3 | 3 | m |
| 2 | 2009 | 3 | 5 | m |
| 2 | 2010 | 5 | 5 | m |
| 2 | 2013 | 2 | 2 | m |
| 5 | 2013 | 4 | 4 | f |
| 5 | 2014 | 5 | 5 | f |

Target Table (Where I created a new col SurveytTime to mark the ith time one took the survey)

| PersonID | SurveyYear | SurveyTime | SurveyQ1Rating | SurveyQ2Rating | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2013 | 3 | 5 | 4 | f |
| 12 | 2012 | 2 | 4 | 4 | f |
| 12 | 2010 | 1 | 3 | 3 | f |
| 2 | 2007 | 1 | 4 | 4 | m |
| 2 | 2008 | 2 | 3 | 3 | m |
| 2 | 2009 | 3 | 3 | 5 | m |
| 2 | 2010 | 4 | 5 | 5 | m |
| 2 | 2013 | 5 | 2 | 2 | m |
| 5 | 2013 | 1 | 4 | 4 | f |
| 5 | 2014 | 2 | 5 | 5 | f |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```r
df |>
  transform(SurveyTime = ave(SurveyYear, PersonID, FUN = rank))
```

Its `dplyr` equivalent:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PersonID) %>%
  mutate(SurveyTime = dense_rank(SurveyYear)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(PersonID = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L), SurveyYear = c(2013L, 2012L, 2010L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L), SurveyQ1Rating = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L), SurveyQ2Rating = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L), Gender = c("f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", 
"m", "m", "f", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, SurveyTime := frank(SurveyYear), PersonID]
```